# Error in the Printing of the Heading for the First Chapter in Table of Contents

Tags: table-of-contents, chapters

As you can see in the image provided below, the TOC page printed "chapter1...1" on the heading for the first chapter. I already looked up my coding and could not find what is the cause of this overlapping error. Can you please help me identify it.

P/s: It worked on my previous laptop where the heading is printed just fine. When I use this new laptop, it became an error like mentioned here.

Coding for the main latex:

```
\documentclass[twoside,tocchapterhead]{UPMthesisEnglish}
\usepackage{paralist}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage[figuresright]{rotating}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{slashbox}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[hmarginratio=2:3]{geometry}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage[chapter]{algorithm}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage[hyphens,spaces]{url}
\allowdisplaybreaks
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\ceil{\lceil}{\rceil}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\floor{\lfloor}{\rfloor}
\newcommand{\dv}{\mid}
\newcommand{\ndv}{\nmid}
\citestyle{apa}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\include{Title}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\textbf{DEDICATIONS}}
\include{Dedication}
\include{Certification}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\textbf{ABSTRACT}}
\include{Abstract}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\textbf{ABSTRAK}}
\include{Abstrak}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\textbf{ACKNOWLEDGMENTS}}
\include{Acknow}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\textbf{DECLARATION}}
\include{Declaration}
\makeatletter \renewcommand{\@dotsep}{10000} \makeatother
\tableofcontents{\protect\thispagestyle{empty}}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\newpage
\mainmatter
\singlespace
\addtocontents{toc}{\addvspace{.5cm}}
\include{Chapter1}
\addtocontents{toc}{\addvspace{.5cm}}
\include{Chapter2} 
\addtocontents{toc}{\addvspace{.5cm}}
\include{Chapter3}  
\addtocontents{toc}{\addvspace{.5cm}}
\include{Chapter4}  
\addtocontents{toc}{\addvspace{.5cm}}
\include{Chapter5}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\textbf{REFERENCES/Bibliography}}
\begin{singlespace}
\bibliography{bibli}
\bibliographystyle{apa}
\end{singlespace}
\newpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\textbf{APPENDICES}}
\appendix
\include{AppendixA} 
\include{AppendixB} 
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\textbf{BIODATA OF STUDENT}}
\include{biodata}  
\end{document}
```

Coding for the Chapter 1 latex:

```
\chapter{\textbf{INTRODUCTION}}\label{cp1}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\vspace{0.5cm}
\section{Elliptic Curves}
...
```

Coding for the latex class:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
% Rand Alfaris's modifications to ccw_chithesis.cls 
% (12th Jul 2008)
% Send comments/changes/questions to <randalfaris@gmail.com>.
% 
% NOTE: Be sure to check your margins carefully on your hardcopy!
%       The top/left/right margins specified in lines 481--488 are
%       exactly what the Dissertation Office specifies, but your printer
%       may print documents offset or stretched by a bit.  One tip is to
%       increase the margins by a fudge factor of 0.05-0.1in; another is
%       to redefine TeX's default \hoffset and \voffset to something
%       other than 1in (e.g., \hoffset=0.95in).  If you do either of 
%       these, PLEASE DON'T PROPAGATE YOUR CHANGES IN THIS FILE.  This
%       class should remain as general-purpose as possible.
%
%       A more elegant solution for offset pages is to use the results
%       of testpage.tex to specify the printer offsets, either in the
%       config.ps in your TeX distribution, or in ~/.dvipsrc.  See the
%       dvips man page for details.
%
% Changes:
%   1) Moved Astronomy-specific modifications to their own package.
%   2) Fixed the bug wherein multipage lists of tables and figures were
%      listed in the TOC with the last page instead of the first.
%   3) Added space between multiple footnotes on a page, as per
%      requirements.  Also made footnote continuation separator the
%      width of text.
%   4) Merged some changes from Martin Pergler's modifications of
%      easychithesis.cls, namely: respace title page a bit, make
%      footnote numbers full size, resize math subscripts, add leader
%      dots to TOC chapters.
%   5) Tweaked margins just slightly to give footer more room. 
%   6) Added "tocchapterhead" option.  This will insert the words 
%      "CHAPTER" and "APPENDIX" as headings in the TOC, although the
%      dissertation format doesn't *require* it.
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
%       Rand's modifications to Craig Wiegert's ccw_chithesis.cls and new hints
%          for formatting the document file.(last updated 26-Jun-2006)
%               1) The acknowledgment environment (as in aastex) has
%                  been changed to invoke \topmatter.
%               2) (moved to astroextras)
%               3) If you want '\\' to force a new line in title then
%                  comment out line 356 and uncomment line 355. Note
%                  however, that this then requires entering the title
%                  in all caps in the document file.
%               4) (moved to astroextras)
%               5) the approval sheet has been add to mutch with upm format
%               6) new designe for the abstract has been add to mutch with upm format 
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%  This is a modification of the 
%
%     easychithesis.cls   Version 1.5   April 5, 1999
%  
%  I (Brad Holden, bph herein) used this for my thesis.  I encountered a
%  few problems when dealing with the Office of Academic
%  Publications so I fixed those in this version.  In the future, 
%  new policies will be enacted so this version will no doubt become
%  obselete as well.
%
%     myeasychithesis.cls   March 13, 2000
%
%
% I (L. Rebull) added a whole bunch of things from aastex.cls file to 
% enable things like deluxetable to work. 
%
%      myeasychithesis2.cls   July, 2000   
%
%     ccw_chithesis.cls       Jun 26 2006
%
% the latest modification is this
% 
%     UPMthesis.cls           Feb 12 2008
%
% I (Rand Alfaris) modified the style of ccw_chithesis.cls and added new 
% extra things to be included in the thesis to be work on
% UPM requirements.
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
%     Original Instructions And Hints
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
% This file provides the LaTeX2e style myeasychithesis for formating
% graduate thesis at the University Putra Malaysia. It was written by
% Rand Alfaris. For an example of its use see the
% file: Randtemplate.tex, and the instructions below.
%
% Comments or problems should be sent to randalfaris@gmail.com
%
%
% Invoking this style:  Start your document with (this is 1.5 spaced)
%
%   \documentclass{myeasychithesis2}
%
% You should submit a double-spaced thesis.  So, start with
%
%   \documentclass[truedoublespace]{myeasychithesis2}
%
% When printing drafts, you may not want your thesis doublespaced.
% If you use instead:
%
%   \documentclass[singlespace]{myeasychithesis2}
%
% or
%
%   \documentclass[onehalfspace]{myeasychithesis2}
%
% your thesis will come out single or 3/2 spaced respectively.
% myeasychithesis2 also understands all options understood by report.
% Also the ``double spacing'' provided by this style is not ``true''
% doublespacing as defined by setspace.sty.  Instead, it is the same
% as on the old LaTeX 2.09 thesis style ``chithesis''.  If you want
% ``true'' double spacing, give the option truedoublespace.
%
% Title Page Information Commands
%    Example Usage:
%       \title{Decimal numbers on cryptography}
%       \author{Rand Q. Alfaris}
%       \department{Mathematics}
%       \division{Pure Mathematics}  (Sciences with an s!)
%       \degree{Doctor of Philosophy}
%       \date{}    
%       \maketitle
%
% \dedication : Use for a dedication, copyright, or epigraph.
%               Produces a page with no number for the text which follows
%               If you want centering, do it yourself with
%               \begin{center} and \end{center}.
%        Usage:
%           \dedication
%           To... .
%
% \topmatter : Things like Abstract, Acknowledgments.
%    Usage:
%       \topmatter{Title Of Matter}
%
%       Use like \chapter, once for each page of matter you want.  Don't
%       use numbered sections within these.  Use \section* instead.
%
% The abstract environment has been changed to invoke \topmatter.
% The acknowledgment environment has been changed to invoke
% \topmatter, use it like the aastex acknowledgment command but put
% it at beginning of document for a UPM Thesis
%
% \mainmatter : Signals the start of the document's body.
%    Usage:
%       \mainmatter
%
%       Use once before the first numbered \chapter.
%
%  HINTS:
%
%  1.  To get appendices, you don't do anything different from a normal
%     report document.  That means, put the command \appendix before
%     you begin your first appendix, then do each appendix with a
%     \chapter command.  Note that if you have only one appendix, it is
%     customary to leave it unnumbered.  Do this with \chapter*.
%
%  2. If you are having page break problems (which are much more
%     likely in double spacing), use the \pagebreak[n] and
%     \nopagebreak[n] commands to tell LaTeX good and bad 
%     places for page breaks. n=1,2,3 for gradually more
%     emphatic suggestion to LaTeX. n=4 is almost always
%     break page or almost never break page.
%
%  3. If you are in a rush and don't have time to go through and
%     rework places which generate overfull hboxes (stuff sticking
%     out from right margin), put the command \sloppy before your
%     \begin{document}. LaTeX will not generate overfull hboxes but will
%     stretch spaces more, beyond its usual aesthetic preferences.
%
%  KNOWN PROBLEMS
%
%  1.  No support for multi-volume theses.
%
%  2.  Doesn't work with older versions of setspace.sty
%
%  3.  Problems with math formulas in chapter headings:
%
%         a.  Any lowercase letters in the formula are converted to
%         uppercase, e.g. f(x) becomes F(X).   If you really need
%         lowercase math letters in your chapter titles, use the
%         option plainchapterheads (and, if you want, type your
%         chapter titles in ALL CAPS so that the appearance doesn't
%         change).  Note there is no problem
%         for section or subsection headings in either case.
%
%         b.  Some perfectly reasonable math commands when used in
%         \chapter give the error
%          ``LATEX ERROR: \command  ALLOWED ONLY IN MATH MODE.''
%         The solution to this is to do
%
%              \newcommand{\mymath}{problem math goes here}
%
%         and then
%
%              \chapter{All about \protect\mymath}
%
%         also, the option plainchapterheads will fix this too.
%
%  Improvements over older versions:
%
%  Added in 1.4: Name of the bibiography is now References, to please the
%  thesis office.  If you want to change it back, put
%
%   \renewcommand{\bibname}{Bibliography}
%
%  in your TeX file prior to \begin{document}
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1995/06/01]
\ProvidesClass{UPMthesis}[2008/07/12 UPM Thesis Class for
LaTex2e]

\RequirePackage{setspace}[1998/04/8]
\newcommand{\etptsize}{12pt}
\DeclareOption{12pt}{\renewcommand{\etptsize}{12pt}}
\DeclareOption{12pt}{\renewcommand{\etptsize}{12pt}}
\DeclareOption{12pt}{\renewcommand{\etptsize}{12pt}}
\DeclareOption{12pt}{\renewcommand{\etptsize}{12pt}}
\DeclareOption{letterpaper}{\PassOptionsToClass{letterpaper}{report}}

% the following is to organize and to add the word "Page" to the tables of contents (Rand)

\addtocontents{toc}{\addvspace{0.5cm}}
\addtocontents{toc}{\hspace{14cm}\textbf{Page}}
\addtocontents{toc}{\addvspace{0.2cm}}

% this to organize and to add the words "Table" and "Page" to the list of tables (Rand)

\addtocontents{lot}{\addvspace{0.5cm}{}\par}
\addtocontents{lot}{{\hspace{.5cm}}\textbf{Table}{\hspace{12.3cm}}{\textbf{Page}}\par}

% this to organize and to add the words "Figure" and "Page" to the list of figures (Rand)

\addtocontents{lof}{\addvspace{0.5cm}{}\par}
\addtocontents{lof}{{\hspace{.5cm}}\textbf{Figure}{\hspace{12.1cm}}{\textbf{Page}}\par}

% The following options set the UPM of spacing

\newcommand{\etspacing}{\setstretch{2}}
\newcommand{\linespacing}{1.5}
\newcommand{\normalspacing}{1.5}
\newcommand{\tablespacing}{2}
\newcommand{\algorithmspacing}{1.05}
\newcommand{\preamblespacing}{1.1}
\newcommand{\proofindent}{0pt}
\DeclareOption{truedoublespace}{\renewcommand{\etspacing}{\doublespacing}}
\DeclareOption{doublespace}{\renewcommand{\etspacing}{\setstretch{2}}}
\DeclareOption{onehalfspace}{\renewcommand{\etspacing}{\onehalfspacing}}
\DeclareOption{singlespace}{\renewcommand{\etspacing}{\singlespacing}}

% Normally, the chapter heads are all uppercase, but sometimes
% this causes problems.  The following option changes
% the chapter heads to small caps instead.

\newcommand{\etchapterheadstyle}[1]{\MakeUppercase{#1}}
\DeclareOption{plainchapterheads}{\renewcommand{\etchapterheadstyle}[1]{#1}}

% This option puts "CHAPTER" and "APPENDIX" headings into the TOC.
% LaTeX omits them by default.  (RAND)

\let\iftocflag=\iffalse
\DeclareOption{tocchapterhead}{\let\iftocflag=\iftrue}

% Pass all other options to report.cls.
\DeclareOption*{%
 \PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{report}
}

% It would be better to have the following line next,
% rather than setting the defaults manually, but
% this would break early versions of LaTeX2e
%
\ExecuteOptions{12pt,letterpaper,doublespace}
\ProcessOptions\relax
\LoadClass[\etptsize]{report}

% RAND: Footnote modifications
% Lengthen continuation rule line for footnotes 
\RequirePackage[splitrule]{footmisc}%
% Add spacing between multiple footnotes, but make sure space isn't
% added between rule and notes.  This is a bit of a kludge.
\setlength{\footnotesep}{\baselineskip}
\let\oldfootnoterule = \footnoterule
\renewcommand{\footnoterule}{\kern 0.4\footnotesep\oldfootnoterule\kern-0.4\footnotesep}
% Make footnote numbers in footnotes regular size, as per ``modern practice''
\renewcommand{\@makefntext}[1]{\noindent\makebox[2.5em][r]{\@thefnmark.\ }#1}

% RAND: font size modifications, from Rand Alfaris
% Put it at document start, else some packages may clobber it.
% Dissertation Office says minimum should be 9pt for microfilming, but
% they didn't actually complain about the standard LaTeX sizes (12/8/6)
% that I used previously.  So 8pt isn't too much of a cheat.
\AtBeginDocument{\DeclareMathSizes{12}{12}{10}{8}}

% Adjust spacing of document

\etspacing
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt} 

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
%     Commands Defined For Use By Thesis Author
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
% \dedication : Use for a dedication, copyright, or epigraph.
%               Produces a page with no number for the text which follows
%               If you want centering, do it yourself with
%               \begin{center} and \end{center}.
%
\newcommand{\dedication}{
        \chapter*{}
        \thispagestyle{empty}
}
% No copyright in UPM equirments.
% copyright page (if used, should appear directly after title page)
% usage: \makecopyright
%\def\makecopyright{\@restonecolfalse
%   \if@twocolumn\@restonecoltrue\onecolumn
%   \else \newpage \fi
%   \thispagestyle{empty}%\setcounter{page}{2}%
%%   \addtocounter{page}{1}
%   \null\vfill
%\centerline{   Copyright \copyright\ \number\year\ by \@author }
%\centerline{ All rights reserved }
%   \vskip 15pt\relax
%   \if@restonecol\twocolumn \else \newpage \fi
%   \let\makecopyright=\relax}

\newcommand{\topmatter}[1]{
        \chapter*{#1}
        \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}
}

%
% redefinition of abstract environment
%

%\renewenvironment{abstract}{\topmatter{Abstract}}{}
%\newenvironment{acknowledgments}{\topmatter{Acknowledgments}}{}


% \mainmatter : Signals the start of the document's body.
%    Usage:
%       \mainmatter
%
%       Use once before the first numbered \chapter.
%
\newcommand{\mainmatter}{
        \clearpage
        \pagenumbering{arabic}
}

\renewcommand{\title}[1]{\gdef\@title{#1}}
\renewcommand{\author}[1]{\gdef\@author{#1}}
\newcommand{\department}[1]{\gdef\@department{#1}}
\newcommand{\division}[1]{\gdef\@division{#1}}
\newcommand{\degree}[1]{\gdef\@degree{#1}}
\renewcommand{\date}[1]{\gdef\@date{#1}}

%
 %\maketitle :  Makes the UPM dissertation title page.

%\renewcommand{\maketitle}
{
%  \begin{titlepage}
%    \begin{center}
%      \rule{0in}{0.25in}
%      \vfill
%%      \@title\\
%      \MakeUppercase{\@title}\\
%      \vfill
%      A DISSERTATION SUBMITTED TO\\
%      THE FACULTY OF THE DIVISION OF THE \MakeUppercase{\@division}\\
%      IN CANDIDACY FOR THE DEGREE OF\\
%      \MakeUppercase{\@degree}\\
%      \ \\
%      DEPARTMENT OF \MakeUppercase{\@department}\\
%      \vfill
%      BY\\
%      \MakeUppercase{\@author}\\
%      \vfill
%      CHICAGO, ILLINOIS\\
%      \MakeUppercase{\@date}
%      \vspace*{0.45in}
%    \end{center}
%  \end{titlepage}
  \pagenumbering{roman}
  \addtocounter{page}{1}
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
%     Internal Formatting Commands For This Thesis Style
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
% Redo commands that make chapter & section headers
%
\renewcommand{\@makechapterhead}[1]{{
        \setlength{\topmargin}{2in}   % really 1.5in, added by bph
                                        % to meet OAP standards
        \normalfont\normalsize\bfseries  %the size of the font of the headers of the chapter
        \begin{center}
        \etchapterheadstyle{\@chapapp{ \thechapter}}  %  CHAPTER 1 or APPENDIX
        \vskip .5cm \@plus \p@

        \etchapterheadstyle{#1}                       %     TITLE OF CHAPTER
        \end{center}
        \setlength{\topmargin}{1.5in}   % back to 1in

}}
\renewcommand{\@makeschapterhead}[1]{{ 

        \setlength{\topmargin}{2in}   % really 1.5in, added by bph
                                        % to meet OAP standards
        \normalfont\normalsize\bfseries   
        \begin{center}
        \etchapterheadstyle{#1}                       %     TITLE OF CHAPTER
        \end{center}
        \setlength{\topmargin}{2in}   % back to 1in
}}
\renewcommand\section{\@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}%
                                {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                {2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
                                {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
\renewcommand\subsection{\@startsection{subsection}{2}{\z@}%
                                {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                {1.5ex \@plus .2ex}%
                                {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}                          
\renewcommand\subsubsection{\@startsection{subsubsection}{3}{\z@}%
                                {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                {1.5ex \@plus .2ex}%
                                {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}                          
\renewcommand\paragraph{\@startsection{paragraph}{4}{\z@}%
                                {3.25ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                {-1em}%
                                {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
\renewcommand\subparagraph{\@startsection{subparagraph}{5}{\parindent}%
                                {3.25ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                {-1em}%
                                {\normalfont\normalsize\itshape}}

% Change style of printing chapters in TOC to match chapter headings.

\renewcommand*\l@chapter[2]{%
  \ifnum \c@tocdepth >\m@ne
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}%
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2} %   
    \addpenalty{-\@highpenalty}%
    \vskip .1cm \@plus \p@ %{the v-distance between the headings in the contents}
    \setlength\@tempdima{1.5em}% %{the distance between the number of the chapter and its title}
    \begingroup
           \parindent\z@ \rightskip \@pnumwidth
            \parfillskip -\@pnumwidth
      \leavevmode
      \advance \leftskip \@tempdima 
      \hskip  -\leftskip 
      \etchapterheadstyle{#1}\nobreak
% CCW: The following 3 lines add dots to the chapter TOC listings
      \leaders\hbox{$\m@th
        \mkern \@dotsep mu\hbox{.}\mkern \@dotsep
        mu$}\hfill
      \hfil \nobreak\hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hss #2}\par
      \penalty\@highpenalty
    \endgroup
  \fi}

% Add "CHAPTER"/"APPENDIX" headings to TOC before first of each.
% If you want these words to be a bit bigger, remove "\normalsize" 
% from the definition below.  If you want the words to be bold, 
% remove "\mdseries". (CCW)


\iftocflag
\let\old@chapter = \@chapter
\def\@chapter[#1]#2{\ifnum\c@chapter=\z@%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\contentsline{part}%
      {\normalsize\etchapterheadstyle{\@chapapp}}{}}%
  \fi%
   \old@chapter[{#1}]{#2}}
  \fi

 
% Change names of table of contents and bibliography

\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of Contents}
\renewcommand{\bibname}{Bibliography}

% Change the margins to fit requirements

\setlength{\topmargin}{0cm}   % really 1in
\setlength{\headheight}{4mm}
\setlength{\headsep}{7mm}
\setlength{\topskip}{0cm}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{1.4cm}  % really 1.5in
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{0.5in}  % really 1.5in
\setlength{\textwidth}{14.7cm}
\setlength{\textheight}{23.0cm}
\setlength{\footskip}{0.3in}

% Changing where the page numbers go on pages that aren't the first
% page of a chapter.

\pagestyle{myheadings}
\markright{}

%Rand: located the page number in the bottom center of the page


\def\@oddfoot{\hss\thepage\hss} \def\@evenfoot{\hss\thepage\hss}
\let\@oddhead\@empty \let\@evenhead\@empty 

% Make the table of contents, etc.,  single spaced
%
% bph added lists of tables/figures to table of contents.
% CCW fixed bug where multipage LOT/LOF were listed in TOC with wrong
% page number.

\let\oldtableofcontents = \tableofcontents
\renewcommand{\tableofcontents}{
  \begin{singlespace}
%\normalspacing
    \oldtableofcontents
  \end{singlespace}
}

\let\oldlistoftables = \listoftables
\renewcommand{\listoftables}{
  \begin{singlespace}
    % This works b/c multiple \newpage's are treated as one
    \newpage
    
    \let\oldcaption = \caption
    \renewcommand{\caption}{
      % \addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
      
  \oldcaption
}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\textbf{List of Tables}}
    \oldlistoftables 
  \end{singlespace}
}

\let\oldlistoffigures = \listoffigures
\renewcommand{\listoffigures}{
  \begin{singlespace}
    % This works b/c multiple \newpage's are treated as one
    \newpage
    \let\oldcaption = \caption
\renewcommand{\caption}{
%            \addtocontents{lof}{\addvspace{2cm}}
\begin{singlespace}
        \oldcaption
          \end{singlespace}
}

    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\textbf{List of Figures}}
    \oldlistoffigures 
  \end{singlespace}
}
%\renewcommand\appendixname{APPENDICES}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[chapter]
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}[chapter]
\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}[chapter]
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}[chapter]
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[chapter]
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}[chapter]
\newtheorem{note}{Note}[chapter]
\newtheorem{example}{Example}[chapter]
\newtheorem{conjecture}{Conjecture}[chapter]

\newenvironment{proof} {\noindent{\bf Proof:} \\ \noindent}

% End of File
```

[image]

Comment: Don't use `\textbf{...}` in chapter titles. Selecting the font shape for such titles is task for document designer (TeX macro programmer), not for author's markup.

Comment: @wipet Hi there, I tried removing the \textbf{...} but it still does not resolve the problem. It only un-bolded the words that I want to bold.

Comment: you have not posted any code relevant to to your problem so it is very hard to help. You presumably have an error in your chapter heading setup that is making it write an incorrect table of contents but you have not provided any example that shows that. You should not have `\textbf` of `\thispagestyle{mpty}` the fonts and page style of chapter openings should b especified just once at the document level, but they will not affect the table of contents.

Comment: @AzmadiM I didn't say about correcting your problem. Your problem is invisible from your shown examples. I just did say about bad convention in your chapter titles.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I provided the class for the latex program which is probably the cause of error because there are no other coding left besides the other chapters which I think are not related. The coding is given to us in advance to use as the article class.

Comment: @wipet Oh my bad, it is well-noted. I used the specifications because I've seen some solutions online about it since I did not know how to make the titles bolded as what required by my institution.